# When the date is selected in JDateChooser the day is incorrect. why?

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar, jdatechooser

When is select the 1st day of the month ex:- 1st of April 2014,

it displays as : **91-04-2014** in the jdatechooser, my dateFormatString is : **"dd-mm-yyyy"**

Here is my code :

```
public class Student extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Student
     */
    static JFormattedTextField gradeText;

    public Student() {
        //Methods
        initComponents();
        KeyTypos();
        updateTable();


        //Frame settings
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("src\\main\\java\\com\\cyrax\\images\\Icon.png");
        this.setIconImage(ic.getImage());

        //initializations
        stud.clearSelection();
        gradeText = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) grd.getEditor()).getTextField();
        dob.setDateFormatString("DD-MM-YYYY");


    }


    public final void KeyTypos() {

      try {
        gradeText = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) grd.getEditor()).getTextField();
        gradeText.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char c = e.getKeyChar();
                if (!(c >= '0' & c <= '9') | c == e.VK_PERIOD) {
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                    e.consume();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if (!gradeText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(gradeText.getText());

                    if (val > 11) {
                        String oldVal = gradeText.getText().toString();
                        char str[] = oldVal.toCharArray();
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(oldVal);
                        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
                        String newVal = sb.toString();
                        gradeText.setText(newVal);

                    }
                }

            }
        });
      }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jToolBar1 = new javax.swing.JToolBar();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        stud = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lname = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        fname = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        mname = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        mtp = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        addr = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        em = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        sch = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        ftp = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        grd = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
        dob = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Student");
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jToolBar1.setFloatable(false);
        jToolBar1.setRollover(true);

        jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/cyrax/images/save.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setBorderPainted(false);
        jButton1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jButton1.setFocusable(false);
        jButton1.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jButton1.setRolloverIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/cyrax/images/rolledsave.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jToolBar1.add(jButton1);

        jButton2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/cyrax/images/delete.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setBorderPainted(false);
        jButton2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jButton2.setFocusable(false);
        jButton2.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jButton2.setRolloverIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/cyrax/images/rolleddelete.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        jToolBar1.add(jButton2);

        jButton3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/cyrax/images/update.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setBorderPainted(false);
        jButton3.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jButton3.setFocusable(false);
        jButton3.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jButton3.setRolloverIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/cyrax/images/rolledupdate.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        jToolBar1.add(jButton3);

        jButton4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/cyrax/images/Sign-Refresh-icon.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton4.setFocusable(false);
        jButton4.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jButton4.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        jToolBar1.add(jButton4);

        jPanel1.add(jToolBar1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 1250, 60));

        stud.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Student ID", "Student Name", "DOB", "Address", "Mothers TP", "Fathers TP", "School", "Grade", "E-mail"
            }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(stud);

        jPanel1.add(jScrollPane1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 70, 1230, 190));

        jLabel1.setText("Last Name        :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 370, -1, 20));

        jLabel2.setText("Mothers TP     :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(300, 370, -1, 20));

        jLabel3.setText("Middle Name     :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 330, -1, 20));
        jPanel1.add(lname, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 370, 170, 20));
        jPanel1.add(fname, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 290, 170, 20));
        jPanel1.add(mname, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 330, 170, 20));

        jLabel4.setText("First Name        :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 290, -1, 20));

        jLabel5.setText("Grade             :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(590, 370, -1, 20));
        jPanel1.add(mtp, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(390, 370, 170, 20));

        jLabel6.setText("Address          :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(300, 330, -1, 20));

        jLabel7.setText("DOB                :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(300, 290, -1, 20));

        jLabel8.setText("E-mail            :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel8, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(880, 290, -1, 20));

        jLabel9.setText("School            :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel9, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(590, 330, -1, 20));
        jPanel1.add(addr, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(390, 330, 170, 20));
        jPanel1.add(em, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(960, 290, 170, 20));
        jPanel1.add(sch, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(680, 330, 170, 20));

        jLabel10.setText("Fathers TP     :");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel10, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(590, 290, -1, 20));
        jPanel1.add(ftp, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(680, 290, 170, 20));

        grd.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 11, 1));
        grd.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
                grdStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        grd.addInputMethodListener(new java.awt.event.InputMethodListener() {
            public void caretPositionChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
            }
            public void inputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
                grdInputMethodTextChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        grd.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                grdKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(grd, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(680, 370, 170, -1));
        jPanel1.add(dob, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(390, 290, 170, -1));

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 1250, 430));

        jMenu1.setText("File");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Edit");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void grdStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                 
    }                                

    private void grdInputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {                                           
    }                                          

    private void grdKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                             
    }                            

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            if(fieldCheck() && dateCheck()){

            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaAluOxideLookAndFeel());
                    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                    new Student().setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            }
        });
    }


    private void updateTable() {
        try {
            ResultSet rs = DB.search("select * from stud");
            DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) stud.getModel();
            Vector v = new Vector();
            while (rs.next()) {
                dtm.setRowCount(0);
                v.add(rs.getString(1));
                v.add(rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3) + " " + rs.getString(4));
                v.add(rs.getString(5));
                v.add(rs.getString(6));
                v.add(rs.getString(7));
                v.add(rs.getString(8));
                v.add(rs.getString(9));
                v.add(rs.getString(10));
                v.add(rs.getString(11));
                dtm.addRow(v);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private boolean fieldCheck() {
         if(fname.getText().toString().isEmpty() || 
           ((JTextField)dob.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
                 addr.getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
                 sch.getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
                 gradeText.getText().isEmpty()) {

               return false;
         }else {
             return true;
         }
    }

    private boolean dateCheck() {
        int daT = Integer.parseInt(((JTextField)dob.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText().toString().replace("-", ""));
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
        String date = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR))+String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH))+String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        int compDate = Integer.parseInt(date);

        if(daT > compDate){
            return false;

        }else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code without initcomponents :

```
public class Student extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Student
     */
    static JFormattedTextField gradeText;

    public Student() {
        //Methods
        initComponents();
        KeyTypos();
        updateTable();


        //Frame settings
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("src\\main\\java\\com\\cyrax\\images\\Icon.png");
        this.setIconImage(ic.getImage());

        //initializations
        stud.clearSelection();
        gradeText = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) grd.getEditor()).getTextField();
        dob.setDateFormatString("DD-MM-YYYY");


    }


    public final void KeyTypos() {

      try {
        gradeText = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) grd.getEditor()).getTextField();
        gradeText.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char c = e.getKeyChar();
                if (!(c >= '0' & c <= '9') | c == e.VK_PERIOD) {
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                    e.consume();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if (!gradeText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(gradeText.getText());

                    if (val > 11) {
                        String oldVal = gradeText.getText().toString();
                        char str[] = oldVal.toCharArray();
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(oldVal);
                        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
                        String newVal = sb.toString();
                        gradeText.setText(newVal);

                    }
                }

            }
        });
      }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    try {
            if(fieldCheck() && dateCheck()){

            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaAluOxideLookAndFeel());
                    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                    new Student().setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            }
        });
    }


    private void updateTable() {
        try {
            ResultSet rs = DB.search("select * from stud");
            DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) stud.getModel();
            Vector v = new Vector();
            while (rs.next()) {
                dtm.setRowCount(0);
                v.add(rs.getString(1));
                v.add(rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3) + " " + rs.getString(4));
                v.add(rs.getString(5));
                v.add(rs.getString(6));
                v.add(rs.getString(7));
                v.add(rs.getString(8));
                v.add(rs.getString(9));
                v.add(rs.getString(10));
                v.add(rs.getString(11));
                dtm.addRow(v);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private boolean fieldCheck() {
         if(fname.getText().toString().isEmpty() || 
           ((JTextField)dob.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
                 addr.getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
                 sch.getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
                 gradeText.getText().isEmpty()) {

               return false;
         }else {
             return true;
         }
    }

    private boolean dateCheck() {
        int daT = Integer.parseInt(((JTextField)dob.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText().toString().replace("-", ""));
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
        String date = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR))+String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH))+String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        int compDate = Integer.parseInt(date);

        if(daT > compDate){
            return false;

        }else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Pls Help me with this

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DD` is day in year. You want `dd` for day in month. See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).